# Set and Get position of gazebo model, using ROS plugin

Tags: gazebo-1.5

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

What is the right way to handle the joints position using given ROS plugin?

Best Regards,

Salman

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2341/set-and-get-position-of-gazebo-model,-using-ros-plugin./) by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 131 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-05-23**:
Hi. I am curretnly working on the same topic. would you like to share some of your idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I will write a short example how to listen to a ROS topic, and control the joint regarding the position you get from the topic, the control will be via a PID controller. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) is some info about PID controllers.

You will change the value of the joint target position in the Callback function, and compute the effort and apply it on the joint in the OnUpdate() function.

Then you can just create a ROS subscriber and init the PID in your Load() function, something like:

```
void ROSPlugin::Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr /*_sdf*/)
    {

      int argc = 0;
      char** argv = NULL;
      ros::init(argc,argv,"ROS plugin");
      this->rosnode = new ros::NodeHandle();

      // Store the pointer to the model
      this->model = _parent;

      // Store the joint you want to control
      this->joint = this->model->GetJoint("joint_name");

      // initialize the pid ( common::Pid ), 
      // you have to see for yourself which values works best for you
      this->jointPID (10, 0, 0, 10, -10);

      // subscribing to the rost topic, and calling the callback function
      this->ROS_subscriber = this->rosnode->subscribe("/ROS_topic", 10, &ROSPlugin::ROSCallback, this);

      // Listen to the update event. This event is broadcast every simulation iteration.
      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart(boost::bind(&DataGlovePlugin::OnUpdate, this));

    }
```

The callback function from the ROS topic:

```
void ROSPlugin::ROSCallback(const package_name::MsgType& msg)
{
     // you update the position of where you want the joint to move
     this->joint_target_pos = msg.pos;
}
```

The OnUpdate() function:

```
void ROSPlugin::OnUpdate()
{
    // compute the steptime for the PID
    common::Time currTime = this->model->GetWorld()->GetSimTime();
    common::Time stepTime = currTime - this->prevUpdateTime;
 this->prevUpdateTime = currTime;

   // set the current position of the joint, and the target position, 
    // and the maximum effort limit
    double pos_target = this->joint_target_pos;
    double pos_curr = this->joint->GetAngle(0).Radian();
    double max_cmd = this->joint_max_effort;

    // calculate the error between the current position and the target one
    double pos_err = pos_curr - pos_target;

    // compute the effort via the PID, which you will apply on the joint
    double effort_cmd = this->jointPID.Update(pos_err, stepTime);
    
    // check if the effort is larger than the maximum permitted one
    effort_cmd = effort_cmd > max_cmd ? max_cmd :
                (effort_cmd < -max_cmd ? -max_cmd : effort_cmd);

    // apply the force on the joint
    this->joint->SetForce(0, effort_cmd);

}
```

If you have problems implementing the idea let me know.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-12**:
Thanks Andrei, m gona try it. I hope it will work for me =)

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-18**:
That's great, Andrei.  Have you considered working this into a tutorial on the wiki?

**Comment by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) on 2013-04-19**:
Thanks, I did not think about it, but if you think it's worth it, I could complete plugin and write it as a tutorial. I just need to know where to put it, and under which title.

**Comment by [Ben B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/136/ben-b/) on 2013-04-19**:
It could expand this one: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros_enabled_model_plugin  or be a second part to it -- under the "ROS Integration" section.

**Comment by [gazer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/344/gazer/) on 2013-06-14**:
is this working?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Cannot tell for the v1.5, but in v1.4 you can use ROS plugins from [`gazebo`](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo) and [`pr2_gazebo_plugins`](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins) packages to control a kinematic chain. There are also `GazeboRosDiffdrive` plugin in [`gazebo_plugins`](http://ros.org/wiki/gazebo_plugins) package.

So, it really depends on complexity of your system and the control goals.

For instance, to control robotic arm with `robot_mechanism_controllers` you will need to do the following:

1. Start `gazebo` with ROS API plugin:

   $ gazebo -s libgazebo_ros_api_plugin.so
2. Add `pr2_controller_manager` to your SDF model file:

   ...
          
              ...
3. Now you can use ROS [`robot_mechanism_controllers`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_mechanism_controllers) with your model.

Of course you have to add the paths to these plugins to `GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH`.

Above approach suits my specific needs, though you may find it more appropriate to write your own [ROS-enabled model plugin](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/ros_enabled_model_plugin). Also see this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.5/plugins/model_manipulation_plugin).

I was unable to make it all work with v1.5, so it might be necessary to modify some sources.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) with karma: 330 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skhan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/266/skhan/) on 2013-04-12**:
Thanks Boris, I give it a try and also wait that someone post a precise solution.